# Why am I getting IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group a DataFrame `per_school_summary` by `"School Type"` and average the results. I'm receiving `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).` for the following code:

```
type_passing_math = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"]).mean()[
    per_school_summary["Average Math Score"] >= 70
]
```

`per_school_summary.head()` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqAw3.png).

What I don't understand is that I've used very similar syntax previously in the same document without error.
In calculating the schools with math scores of 70 or higher, I have the following code:

```
school_passing_math = school_data_complete[school_data_complete["math_score"] >= 70]
```

`school_data_complete.head()` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH2hq.png).

`school_passing_math.head()` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC3Sg.png).

I've tried doing

```
type_passing_math = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"]).mean()[
    per_school_summary["Average Math Score"].groupby(["School Type"]) >= 70
]
```

but then I merely receive `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'int'`.

I've also tried

```
type_passing_math = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"]).mean().loc[
    per_school_summary["Average Math Score"] >= 70
]
```

but receive the same error in the title.

Answer (score 1):

This bit doesn't make sense, as a `SeriesGroupBy` cannot be used directly as a `Series`:

```
type_passing_math = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"]).mean()[
    per_school_summary["Average Math Score"].groupby(["School Type"]) >= 70
]
```

If you want to filter the aggregated data, you probably want [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on the output of the aggregation:

```
s = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"])["Average Math Score"].mean()
type_passing_math = s[s >= 70]
```

Example output (the average above threshold are reporter):

```
s = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"])["Average Math Score"].mean()
type_passing_math = s[s >= 70]

School Type
B    90.0
Name: Average Math Score, dtype: float64
```

Or, to filter the original DataFrame use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
s = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"])["Average Math Score"].transform('mean')
type_passing_math = per_school_summary[s >= 70]
```

Example output (the rows for which the group has an average above threshold are reported):

```
s = per_school_summary.groupby(["School Type"])["Average Math Score"].transform('mean')
type_passing_math = per_school_summary[s >= 70]

  School Type  Average Math Score
1           B                  80
4           B                 100
```

Used input example:

```
per_school_summary = pd.DataFrame({'School Type': list('ABCABCAC'),
                                   'Average Math Score':[50, 80, 80, 90, 100, 60, 40, 20]})
```

Answer (score 0):

If need filter rows in `per_school_summary` use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for return mask with same index like `per_school_summary`:

```
mask = per_school_summary.groupby("School Type")["Average Math Score"].transform('mean')>=70
type_passing_math = per_school_summary[mask]
```

If need filter aggreagted values of Series `series` use:

```
series = per_school_summary.groupby("School Type")["Average Math Score"].mean()
type_passing_math = series [series  >= 70]
```

**Sample**:

```
per_school_summary = pd.DataFrame({'School Type':['type1', 'type2','type1',
                                                  'type2','type1', 'type2'],
                                   'Average Math Score':[100,50,80,20,30,100]})

mask=per_school_summary.groupby("School Type")["Average Math Score"].transform('mean')>=70
type_passing_math = per_school_summary[mask]
print (type_passing_math)
  School Type  Average Math Score
0       type1                 100
2       type1                  80
4       type1                  30

series = per_school_summary.groupby("School Type")["Average Math Score"].mean()
print (series)
School Type
type1    70.000000
type2    56.666667
Name: Average Math Score, dtype: float64


type_passing_math = series [series  >= 70]
print (type_passing_math)
School Type
type1    70.0
Name: Average Math Score, dtype: float64
```